# Conjugate in Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality for Complex Numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Simple question: do we really need the conjugate in the inequality?

$$ |\sum_{j=1}^n a_j \overline{b_j}|^2 \leq \sum_{j=1}^n |a_j|^2 \sum_{j=1}^n |b_j|^2 $$

Comment: The answer is No.

Comment: Of course no: replace all $b_j$ by their conjugates, the inequality is still true, and $|b_j|=|\bar{b}_j|$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality says that $|\langle a,b \rangle| \leq \| a \| \|b\|$.  In $\mathbb C^n$, the inner product is
\begin{equation}
\langle a, b \rangle = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \bar{b_j}.
\end{equation}

That's why the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in $\mathbb C^n$ has conjugates in it.

While it is true that you could omit the conjugates in your inequality and still have a true statement, that would only take us further away from the nice statement that $|\langle a,b \rangle| \leq \| a \| \|b\|$.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. Haven't read about the inner product for complex numbers yet

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no, because $|b_j|^2=|\bar{b}_j|^2$.

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer, yes. Look back to the definition of the inner product (for complex numbers) and note the complex conjugate symmetry (as opposed to pure symmetry)

Comment: If you replace $b_j$ by $\overline{b_j}$ on both sides, you have no more $\overline{.}$ on the left and on the right, you don't have any either since you have $|b_j| = |\overline{b_j}|$...